# Core data with images

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm new to iOS app development. My first question is it possible to create a core data entity that will have both text and images included? so attributes will be: Name, Price, Detail and Image.  if so, how can I preload the data into the database?

Comment: Yes you can have an image stored in core data but it is quite common to store the image outside of core data and then store a url to the file instead in core data. Other than that I think your question is to broad and that you need to do some more research so you can ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 0):

you have to change image into (pngData) them save it and then when reading the image change (pngData) to image

and in core Data model make the image attribute of type binary Data

that source will help
https://blog.devgenius.io/saving-images-in-coredata-8739690d0520